# Split line by character separator and subelements

Tags: regex

In this string:

```
#animal the cat   #tree palm tree
```

I want to match

```
#animal  
the cat
```

and

```
#tree  
palm tree
```

I have found several ways to match the first one but I have problems stopping at the second #  character and continue from there.

```
(?<=#)(\w*)\s(.*)(?!#)
```

finds only one match capturing everything after `#animal` until the end.

Lazyfiying the capturer next to the tag captures the tags

```
(?<=#)(\w*)\s(.*?)(?!#)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```js
(#\w+)\s+(.*?)(?=#\w|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUxvEn/1).

If there can be line breaks, you may replace `.` with `[\s\S]` / `[\w\W]` / `[\d\D]` / `(?s:.*?)` or just prepend the pattern with `(?s)`.

*Details*:

- `(#\w+)` - Group 1: a `#` char and then one or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=#\w|$)` - immediately to the right, there must be `#` and one or more word chars or end of string.